# Scala-Not compiling for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

I am trying to run the following code:

```
def split(input: Int): List[Int] = {
  val inputAsString = input.toString
  val inputAsStringList = inputAsString.split("").toList
  inputAsStringList.map(_.toInt).reverse
}

split(3122)

def increment(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def loop(multiplier: Int, result: List[Int], list: List[Int]): List[Int] = list match {
    case x :: xs =>
      val newList = (x * multiplier) :: result
      loop(multiplier * 10, newList, xs)
    case Nil => result
  }

  loop(1, List(), list)
}

val result: List[Int] = for {
  splited <- split(3122)
  incremented <- increment(splited)
} yield incremented
```

But the line `incremented <- increment(splited)` is giving the following error:

> Type mismatch, expected: List[Int], actual: Int

Why is this happening if both functions are returning the same data type?

Comment: BTW, your `loop()` doesn't loop.

Comment: @jwvh I have changed the increment function. Now it loops correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your `increment` function takes a `List[Int]`, but `splited` is an `Int` while in the for comprehension. This is because at the line `splited <- split(3122)`, you are really saying `for every x: Int in split(y): List[Int]`. If you want it to compile, you want your `val result` code to look like this:

```
...
val splited = split(3122)

val result: List[Int] = for {
  incremented <- increment(splited)
} yield incremented
```

This returns `result: List[Int] = List(2)`. Whether you expect this or not is another thing - I'm not sure what you expect `increment` to return.

Comment: A `for` comprehension that yields the result of its only generator is redundant, the equivalent of a basic assignment: `val result = increment(splited)`

Comment: I know. The question was about why OP's code wouldn't compile though - this isn't the best-_looking_ solution, but it is a solution. I agree that splitting the for comprehension into two val statements is much better though.

Comment: So I should split the for comprehension into two statements? There is not a way to do it in a single statement?

Comment: There's no good reason to, in my opinion. You could write `val result: List[Int] = increment(split(3122))` (outputs `List(3000, 100, 20, 2)`), but while this works I personally prefer to split my stuff over multiple lines, at least before refactoring, as it helps me debug if something goes wrong. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following example to understand what for-comprehension does:

```
//For comprehension:
for {
    a <- aMonad
    b <- bMonad
    //....some more....
    z <- zMonad
} yield {
    ???
}

//means:
aMonad.flatMap { a =>
    bMonad.flatMap { b =>
        //{{{...some more
        //notice here it is .map instead of flatMap
        zMonad.map { z =>
            //something
            ???
        }
        //}}}
    }
}
```

The monads aMonad, bMonad, .. zMonad should be monads of similar types, like, List[_], Future[_] etc to be used in a for-comprehension.

That means, aMonad of type List[Int] and bMonad of type Future[Int] cannot be used in a for-comprehension like in the above code, while there is no problem if they are of List[Int] and List[String] type.

Further readings:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/first-steps-with-monads-in-scala/